# Where to create temp files when access to /tmp/ is denied?

Tags: command-line

I wrote a short bash script to complete a task that involves creating a temporary directory and storing various files in it and performing various operations on it.

In my first pass I just created the temp dir at /tmp/$$.$script", but then I tested the script on a computer where I didn't have write access to /tmp/, and I'd like to take that case into account. So my question is where's a good secondary location for this temp dir? Should I just use the current directory? The home directory? ~/tmp/? The output location of the script?

All created files do get cleaned up on script exit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many systems also have a `/var/tmp`.  If the sysadmin doesn't want you writing in to `/tmp`, presumably they have provided some alternative… is the `$TMPDIR` environment variable set? For example, on my Mac:

```
$ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/jf/jfu4pjGtGGGkUuuq8HL7UE+++TI/-Tmp-/
```

Comment: Unfortunately this particular computer does not have TMPDIR set, but I think I will add a check for that as a possible write location. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest ~/.[your script name]/tmp, if TMPDIR is not set, instead of ~/tmp/ since the user may have created that on their own (and you may not want to accidentally override things in there).

Just as an off the cuff thought in bash --

```
case $TMPDIR in '') tmp_dir=".${0}/tmp";; *) tmp_dir=$TMPDIR;; esac
```

Answer (score 4):

Use ${TMPDIR:-/tmp} ($TMPDIR or /tmp if $TMPDIR is not set). If that's not writable, then exit with an error saying so, or ask the user for input defining it. I think asking the user where temp files should go is preferable to assuming somewhere and leaving them there if your process gets killed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [mktemp](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mktemp) (assuming it's configured correctly for the system)

e.g. 

`MYTMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)`

Answer (score 1):

You could try `/var/tmp`, although it's likely that `/tmp` is a symlink to that (or vice-versa).

Comment: In this particular case I do actually have access to /var/temp, so that's what I'm going with. Thanks.